# junit add more test classes dynamically per user request (rerun tests) for integration testing

Tags: spring, junit, integration-testing

I am looking for a way to start the spring context, intialize all caches and after that ask the user on the command line (cmd) what tests he want to execute.

after the tests are run the user can choose to rerun the tests or run different tests until he decide to stop the programm.

this should be based on junit as it enables us to use the same tests within different execution environments (eg. jenkins build, ...)

is there a framework that support something like this or any other adwise how to implement this?

```
while(true) {
  userInput = parseUserInputFromConsole();
  if (userWantToExit(userInput)) {
    break;
  } else {
    JunitResult = runJunitTetsBasedOnUserInput(userInput);
    generateTestRunReport(JunitResult);
  }
}
```

additional, one test exists of more then one step, but the steps should be reusable among tests. any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Spring `@ActiveProfiles` annotation, you need to basically set which tests are applicable for which run like below:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles({"dev", "integration"})
public class DeveloperIntegrationTests {
    // class body...
}
```

You can look at [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html)

Comment: thanks for the answer. not exactly what I was looking for see my enhanced question with a code example.